# Error End tag missing Update panel

Tags: asp.net, .net, ajax

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>

//some code goes here

</ContentTemplate>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Content>
```

Before applying the Update panel it shows fine.but after adding it it says "Missing end tag".But when run the code it shows perfectly in the browser.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code, try to rebuild or restart visual studio.

Comment: _"But when run the code it shows perfectly in the browse"_ that means it's working.

Comment: "Missing end tag", is it a warning? how does VStudio display this message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You move your Script Manager in your `MasterPage`

MaterPage

```
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>

         <asp:contentplaceholder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
        </asp:contentplaceholder>
    </div>
    </form>
```

Page

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
   <ContentTemplate>

      //some code goes here

   </ContentTemplate>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: I'am happy to help you user1716250